# How to keep adding data frames to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

My input is a list of lists. I am trying to convert each sublist into a data frame with two columns and then convert all the data frames together.

I have about more than 80 sublists in that list, the following is just an example:

```
[[('04-24-2019 18:51:54:629', 'a'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:790', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:934', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:65', 'l'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:157', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:710', 'b'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:862', 'o'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:58:501', 'backspace'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:368', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:507', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:800', 's'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:52:05:502', 'backspace')],
 [('04-24-2019 18:51:54:629', 'a'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:790', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:934', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:65', 'l'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:157', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:710', 'b'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:862', 'o'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:58:501', 'backspace'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:368', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:507', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:800', 's'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:52:05:502', 'backspace')],
 [('04-24-2019 18:51:54:629', 'a'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:790', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:54:934', 'p'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:65', 'l'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:55:157', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:710', 'b'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:57:862', 'o'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:58:501', 'backspace'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:368', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:507', 'e'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:51:59:800', 's'),
  ('04-24-2019 18:52:05:502', 'backspace')]]
```

#### This is converting original data into a list of lists -

```
org_time_list = []
for x in range(len(data)):
    dd = (data[x]["input_clicks"])      
    org_time_list.append(list(dd.items()))
org_time_list
```

#### This is trying to convert each sublist to a data frame and append those data frames together -

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()
for x in org_time_list:
    for y in x:
        df_3.append(pd.DataFrame((y), columns=['Date', 'DateValue']))
df_3
```

I am expecting to have a dataframe that contains all of the data from the list of lists with two columns only. The following is an example of a sublist.

```
Date    DateValue
0   04-24-2019 18:51:54:629 a
1   04-24-2019 18:51:54:790 p
2   04-24-2019 18:51:54:934 p
3   04-24-2019 18:51:55:65  l
4   04-24-2019 18:51:55:157 e
5   04-24-2019 18:51:57:710 b
6   04-24-2019 18:51:57:862 o
7   04-24-2019 18:51:58:501 backspace
8   04-24-2019 18:51:59:368 e
9   04-24-2019 18:51:59:507 e
10  04-24-2019 18:51:59:800 s
11  04-24-2019 18:52:05:502 backspace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this simple approach:

```
import functools
import operator

temp_data = functools.reduce(operator.concat, org_time_list) #flatten the list of lists
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(temp_data, columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
```

If you can show how your original data looks like I think the first loop can be avoided too.